# can't insert a row in a dataframe where index is a datetime

Tags: python, pandas

data is typical stock quotes:

```
                     human_date     open    high     low   close   volume
date                                                                       
2017-10-13 00:00:00  13/10/17 0:00  5464.7  5464.8  5448.8  5448.9  1207430
2017-10-13 00:01:00  13/10/17 0:01  5450.0  5450.9  5434.9  5435.0  1411973
2017-10-13 00:02:00  13/10/17 0:02  5434.4  5437.3  5430.0  5433.6  1537291
2017-10-13 00:03:00  13/10/17 0:03  5433.6  5443.7  5433.6  5442.3   825607
2017-10-13 00:04:00  13/10/17 0:04  5440.0  5444.4  5440.0  5440.0  1018440
```

I have the following code:

```
        r = {
            'open': previous['open'],
            'high': previous['high'],
            'low': previous['low'],
            'close': previous['close'],
            'volume': previous['volume'],
            'date': datetime_to_epoch(now),
            'human_date': now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}
        print(f'fixing {now} with {r}')
        c1 = len(minute_data)
        minute_data.append(pd.DataFrame(r, index=['date']))
        c2 = len(minute_data)
        print(f'data len from {c1} to {c2}')
```

c1 is always equal to c2, so I don't know how to insert a row...

also there is a warning that I do now understand:

> FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned.
>   A future version of pandas will change to not sort by default.
>
> To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.
>
> To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass
>   'sort=True'.
>
> sort=sort,

In typical pandas form: 'non-concatenation axis is not aligned'.. super clear :D

but, the question is: how can I insert a row? the data is missing some times and I need to fill it up so no time frame is missing.

---

Edit:
following Valdi_Bo's answer, I did this:

```
          r = {
                'open': previous['open'],
                'high': previous['high'],
                'low': previous['low'],
                'close': previous['close'],
                'volume': previous['volume'],
                'human_date': hDate
            }

            print(f'fixing {now} with {r}')
            c1 = len(minute_data)
            minute_data.append(pd.DataFrame(r, index=[indDate]))
            c2 = len(minute_data)
```

c1 is still equal to c2 after.

I implemented Jezrael's answer:

```
           r = {
                'open': previous['open'],
                'high': previous['high'],
                'low': previous['low'],
                'close': previous['close'],
                'volume': previous['volume'],
                'human_date': now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            }

            df1 = pd.DataFrame(r)
            df1.index = [datetime_to_epoch('now')]

            print(f'fixing {now} with {r}')
            c1 = len(minute_data)
            minute_data = minute_data.append(df1)
            c2 = len(minute_data)
            print(f'data len from {c1} to {c2}')
```

and got this:

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

during the call to append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `minute_data.append(pd.DataFrame(r, index=['date']))` in your code.

You create a temporary DataFrame. The content of the row looks OK, but
as the index value you attempt to insert `'date'` - a **string**,
whereas it should be of *DateTime* type.

My suggestion:

- Get the current Timestamp, calling *pd.now()*.
- Convert it to human date (*strftime(...)*), almost as you did, but:

  - without seconds / miliseconds (note that previous rows are just
    on full minutes),
  - with format like in existing rows.
- Convert this text to Timestamp (so it will be also without seconds),
  to be used as the index value.
- Create the temporary DataFrame.
- Append it to *minute_data*.

So the code should be:

```
now = pd.now()
hDate = now.strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M") + ":00"
indDate = pd.to_datetime(hDate, dayfirst=True)
r = { ... 
      'human_date': hDate }
minute_data.append(pd.DataFrame(r, index=[indDate]))
```

Comment: almost: minute_data = minute_data.append(...), while minute_data.append(...) doesn't work.  I didn't know that append returned a new object.